# Use JNI to call C functions in host binary

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a JNI C function in the executable that is hosting the JVM. I've compiled with -rdynamic, and confirmed with nm -D that the symbol is exported in the dynamic symbols table. However, when I call it the JVM complains that the symbol can't be found.

I've done this in the past with LuaJIT and it was rather trivial, I'd be pretty surprised if it can't be done with Java.

I created a test method in class JNITest

```
public static native int strLen();
```

And implementation:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <java/com_jnitest_JNITest.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_jnitest_JNITest_strLen(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    return 1111;
}

int main()
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;

    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    std::string classpath = "-Djava.class.path=";
    classpath += "/var/projects/jnitest/src/java";
    options[0].optionString = (char*)classpath.c_str();

    jint result = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
    if (result != JNI_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create JVM" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    jclass main_class = env->FindClass("com/jnitest/JNITest");
    if (main_class == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Could not find JNITest class" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    jmethodID main_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(main_class, "main", "()V");

    // Call JNITest.main() transferring control to Java
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(main_class, main_method, nullptr);

    if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        return 1;
    }

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, Java is not Lua. Second, you might prefer [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) (I know I find it easier).

Comment: Easier, yes, but I need JNI anyway for some functions for performance reasons.

Comment: What functions can you call with jni that you can't call with jna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM only registers all functions inside a shared library if loaded with [System.loadLibrary()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-).

Since you create the JVM inside your programm it doesn't know about this function, you can use [env->RegisterNatives(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods) to link native methods with your java class.

Also the `JNIEXPORT` is not needed because you register it with a function pointer and there is no need to make this method accessible from the outside.

Comment: I thought I left a comment here. Thanks, this solved my problem perfectly and it's much less nasty than the javah and mangled names. I was unable to discover if there's any performance difference, but since dynamic linking essentially works off of function pointers too, I can't imagine this approach being slower.